# What's the meaning of this Oracle SQL code?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been learning Oracle SQL recently and I came across the following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees outer_emps
WHERE (2-1) = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM employees inner_emps
  WHERE inner_emps.salary > outer_emps.salary
);
```

Could someone please help me understand the syntax?

Comment: Certainly the `(2-1)` is a piece of needless obfuscation. Why not just use `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns employees whose salary is the 2nd highest.

For example:

```
SQL> select ename, sal from emp order by sal;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SMITH             840
JAMES             950
ADAMS            1100
WARD             1250
MARTIN           1250
MILLER           1300
TURNER           1500
ALLEN            1600
CLARK            2450
BLAKE            2850
JONES            2975
SCOTT            3000   --> SCOTT and FORD have the 2nd highest salary
FORD             3000   -->
KING             5000   --> KING has the highest salary

14 rows selected.

SQL> select ename, sal
  2  from emp outer_emps
  3  where 1 = (select count(*) from emp inner_emps
  4             where inner_emps.sal > outer_emps.sal);

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SCOTT            3000
FORD             3000

SQL>
```

If you used `<`, you'd get the 2nd lowest salary (that's James because SMITH's salary is 840 - the lowest - and JAMES follows with 950):

```
SQL> select ename, sal
  2  from emp outer_emps
  3  where 1 = (select count(*) from emp inner_emps
  4             where inner_emps.sal < outer_emps.sal);

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
JAMES             950

SQL>
```

---

I'd probably do it as follows; that's easier to understand:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select ename, sal,
  3       rank() over (order by sal desc) rnk
  4     from emp
  5    )
  6  select ename,sal from temp
  7  where rnk = 2;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SCOTT            3000
FORD             3000

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Littlefoot, i've a question please.
Why there's outer_emps and inner_emps without typing a join statement and how can count(*) return data and not a whole number?

Comment: There's no join here, just correlation between table used in subquery (its alias is INNER_EMPS) and table used in the main query (its alias is OUTER_EMPS). Subquery doesn't return any data - it returns NUMBER of rows that satisfy the condition. If you wanted to get e.g. person who has the 5th highest salary, you'd use `where 5 = (select count(*) ...` and get CLARK as result (because SCOTT and FORD have equal salaries).

Comment: Perfect, One last thing, Is the first WHERE condition based on the employee_id or salary and what's the idea behind inner_emps.sal < outer_emps.sal .. i guess both are the same list of salaries correct?

Comment: WHERE isn't related to employee_id nor salary, but *number of rows whose salaries are lower (or higher) than the ones in OUTER_EMPS*.  INNER_EMPS.SAL < (or >) OUTER_EMPS.SAL represents which "side" you're checking - high salaries or low salaries.